# How to test sending email in Laravel 5 using Behat?

Tags: laravel, behat

I've just started learning to work with Behat in Laravel 5 and wonder how I could verify email sending. I tried this [tutorial](http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/using_the_profiler_with_minkbundle.html) but it did not work (maybe it's out of date?). I also tried googling but couldn't find many sources. If you could show me how to achieve this, or direct me to a nice tutorial, I'd be really grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: You would normally mock this functionality. Instead of actually sending the email.
BDD stands by the principal of only testing your own code, so for example, you wouldn't write a test around using the mail() function. Instead your test would be around constructing the email (adding to, from, subject), then checking the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use mailtrap instead of mocking. I find it very usefull.
If you have set all the requirements, you can fetch your last sent mail by this method:

```
$lastEmail = $this->fetchInbox()[0];
```

Then you can retrieve let's say the title like this:

```
$subject = $lastEmail['subject'];
```

For a nice and clean tutorial watch: https://laracasts.com/lessons/trapping-your-email

I hope it helps!